# If B is a subset of A, remove B from a, with elements in the same order

Tags: python, arrays

lets suppose A = `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

If B is a subset of A, say `[2, 1, 3]`;

I want to remove B from A in the same order to get `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

Here's the code I used:

```
_set = [
    1, 2, 3,
    1, 2, 3, 
    2, 1, 3, 
    1, 2, 3
]
subset = [2, 1, 3]

def remove_subset(_set, subset):
    for i in subset:
        _set.remove(i)
    return _set

print(remove_subset(_set, subset))
```

But it gives the output `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

The expected output is: `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Is B guaranteed to be a subset of A, or does it need to be checked and if it isn't, nothing shall be done?

Comment: `set` is a bad idea for name, as it's a built-in function (to create a set; but probably not what you want here). Similarly, I wouldn't use a name starting with an underscore in the global namespace, since that has an odd meaning (it's a private variable). Think up some good names. Perhaps simply `mainset` (compared to `subset`) can work here.

Comment: You're removing the first instance of each element of `subset`.  That's not even close to what you're trying to achieve.  You need to search for the elements in a consecutive sequence.  Also, don't use `set` as a variable name.  `set` is a builtin which you're blocking.

Comment: `remove()` will remove the first matching item

Comment: Your `_set` is not a set. It contains duplicates.

Comment: Is `[1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]` also an acceptable result? I removed 2, 1 and 3 in that order, i.e., I removed the bold ones: [1, **2**, 3, **1**, 2, **3**, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3].

Comment: What's the desired result for `A = [1,2,3]` and `B = [1,3]`?

Comment: There will be no output for `A = [1,2,3]` and `B = [1,3]`. But if `A` is `[1, 3, 2]`, It will remove the `1` and `3` as they are in the same order as they are in `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you're removing the individual elements without paying attention to the order they appear. It looks like you want to delete the elements of the subset only if they appear contiguously in the same order as they do in the subset.

Sadly, this is something Python `list`s won't do for you (there is no equivalent to `str.replace` that allows you to remove a fixed sequence wherever it occurs). So you're stuck finding the index where your subsequence occurs and deleting it from the `list`:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):  # Renamed set to lst, since it is a list, and to avoid shadowing set constructor
    if lst[i:i+len(sublst)] == sublst:  # Renamed subset to sublst to match
        del lst[i:i+len(sublst)]  # We found a place where the sublst begins, slice it out
        break
```

This only removes one copy (to avoid issues with mutating a `list` as you iterate over it, or considering how to handle it if the sublist can overlap itself in the main list).

Side-note: This (iterating over slices of a sequence) is basically the only circumstance in which iterating over sequence indices is the Pythonic solution (there are ways to avoid the unPythonic `for i in range(len(lst)):` involving `enumerate` and `zip` and `iter` and explicit sequence multiplication and star-unpacking, but they're so ugly it's not worth the bother).

Comment: I'd add that you can avoid issues with mutating a list while iterating over it and remove all occurrence of the sublist by simply looping over the list from the end to the start. Something like uisng `for i in range(len(lst)-len(sublst), -1, -len(sublst))` and removing the `break` instruction should work.

Comment: @Xiidref: Presumably you want to step by `-1`, not `-len(sublst)` (unless the sublist must be *aligned* in the list at a multiple of the length relative to the end of the list, which would be a very weird design). Otherwise, yeah, it works, it's just uglier, and I wanted the simple solution first. I'll note you can make it less ugly by just using `range(len(lst))[::-1]` or `reversed(range(len(lst)))` (optionally subtracting `len(sublst)` for a minor efficiency boost) to avoid spelling out three arguments in the ugly way needed to produce a descending `range` object.

Comment: @ShadowRanger If you subtract len(sublst) in those versions, you need to add 1.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to convert your lists to strings and use the `.replace` method of strings -

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 1, 3]
str_a = ''.join(map(str, a))
str_b = ''.join(map(str, b))
str_a_b_removed = str_a.replace(str_b, '')
list(map(int, list(str_a_b_removed)))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This fails the instant an entry stringifies to more than one character (e.g. `10`, `-1`, etc.)...

Comment: It doesn't seem reasonable to assume that all of the numbers are single digit.

Comment: Yes, I agree - this approach will also not be robust against floats. But I'll leave it here for the simplest case.